# Swift firebase log in and admin / nonmember app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, authorization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVbO.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlVbO.png)i want to check snapshot for value in "MembershipStatus".  if MembershipStatus = active then to to one ActiveVC, if not then go to NonActiveVC.  if i could get snapshot to work then i feel i could get the rest working.  just been struggling.

here is my code:

```
// sign in user
 let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in:.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passWordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in:.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let rootref = Database.database().reference().root
    let userRef = rootref.child("users").childByAutoId().child("MembershipStatus")
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

//        __________this code works
//        sign in user

```
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            //could not sign in
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else {

            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                snapshot in
                let value = snapshot.value as? [String?]
                print (value!)}
            )
            //if user is a non active member then...go here to non active member controller

            let homeViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: Constants.Storyboard.homeViewController) as? NonMemberMainVC
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = homeViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


            //if a user is a active member then go to active member controller
                }
        }
        }
```

Comment: well. my firebase has

Comment: users/ some funky userID/ then my list of information for user such as name, uid, member status etc.  i want to be able to recognize usertype before i take user to viewcontroller

Comment: The code in the question is unrelated to the Firebase Real Time Database. What you're asking and what's not working is unclear as well. Can you clarify the question and what code you're having difficulty with?

Comment: Well, the code i show is just basic log in.  so i was showing the auth side of logging into firebase.  after login i want to reference a child from uid (example: member_status: y or n) to see if user is a member.  if they a member then go to one VC if not then another VC.

Comment: Understood. So the question is how to present a view controller? That would not be related to Firebase in that case as the code presented in your question works correctly.

Comment: yes correct, but i only want to present a view controller if a member/user has passed 2 credentials.  1. has created an account, 2. have authorization by me.  i will authorize manually in firebase by creating a value/case in a field under their account.

Comment: i have the following fields: 1. First_name, 2. Last_name, 3. uid (special), 4. email, 5. MembershipStatus

Comment: Ok. So - where's the code you're stuck on? Can you update the question with that code and describe the issue you're having with it? Then we can take a look!

Comment: "rules": 
  {
    "users":
    {
      "$uid": 
      {
        ".read": "auth !=null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
    
  }

}

Comment: i set my rules to:

Comment: The question nor the solution has anything to do with rules what-so-ever. Rules determine what data users do or do not have access to and won't help with displaying viewControllers within your app. You need to incude the code in your question you're having difficulty with. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i thought i did ask the question clearly.  when i scroll up above i see what i posted.  i wrote what my goal was.

Comment: i added a picture showing my code.

Comment: i just want to return the value set in snapshot to return what is stored in users/MembershipStatus.  if i get that working then i can do the rest.

Comment: Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text so we can use them in answers with copy/page. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Images and links are not searchable so they may not be of use to future readers.

Comment: Note that Firebase is asynchronous so the code directly following a firebase function closure will execute before the code in the closure. So this code `let homeViewController = self.storyboard?` will execute before this code does `print (value!)` within the closure. Do a bit of research here on SO about asynchronous functions - it's been addressed lots of times with a ton of example code of how to work with those types of function calls

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60728849/user-profile-information-is-not-showing-up-using-swift-and-firestore-database