# User profile information is not showing up using swift and firestore database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[pic of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcaoo.png)
I am trying to show a label with the user's status on their profile page.  after logging in the user gets presented with a VC that has a side menu.  on that side menu is a "profile" option.  once choosing this they go to their profile controller.  right now i simply need to search users/current uid/ "MembershipStatus" and present this result into a label called "welcomeLabel".

I am returning nul

import UIKit

import Firebase

class NonMemberProfileController: UIViewController {

```
    // MARK: - Properties

var welcomeLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 28)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.alpha = 0
    return label
}()

    // MARK: - Init

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            authenticateUserAndConfigureView()
    }

func loadUserData()
{
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
                                            //.child("MembershipStatus")
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) {
        (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("MembershipStatus"){
            print("true we have bingo")
        } else {
            print("no bueno")
            dump(snapshot)
        }

        guard let status = snapshot.value as? String else { return }
        self.welcomeLabel.text = "Welcome, \(status)"
        print("this is lkjfdskjklsfad" + status)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}

func authenticateUserAndConfigureView(){
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginViewController())
            navController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    } else {
        configureNavigationBar()
        loadUserData()
    }
}

        // MARK: - Selectors

        @objc func handleDismiss() {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        // MARK: - Helper Functions

        func configureNavigationBar() {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            navigationItem.title = "Profile"
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .darkGray
            navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Home_2x").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "baseline_settings_white_24dp").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleDismiss))
            view.addSubview(welcomeLabel)
            welcomeLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
            welcomeLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please double check that your database has the value at that path. If yes then in the completion block of `StatusMembership` observing event print out the snapshot value with dump as `dump(snapshot.value)` to get the response on console to verify that it really has a value.

Comment: one more thing.  my user uid is printing so i am reading that ok.  completely stumped on this..  :-/

Comment: Have you tried printing the snapshot.value ?

Comment: i just updated code to reflect a add in.  i tried the dump(snapshot.value) you suggested and still returned null.

Comment: This is from nonMembermain vc rdHIwVi9kcSaHcmz1H7ejko8xQS2
Show profile
no bueno
- Snap (rdHIwVi9kcSaHcmz1H7ejko8xQS2) <null> #0
  - super: NSObject
*result from code listed above*

Comment: Please share the ss of your database data if possible.

Comment: im sorry.  i dont know what ss means :-(

Comment: i am thinking i may have issue with "realtime" and "cloud".  is this possible?

Comment: it appears that portions of my app speaks with realtime and other with cloud.

Comment: Ss means Screenshot

Comment: oh i did.  its at the top

Comment: Ok so. here is what is happening.  there are 2 firebase databases.  1 is cloud, 1 is realtime.  they do not speak with one another.  you have to write to either one or the other.  the code above is for realtime, but ive been writing to cloud.  this is why user/uid info is null.

Comment: but when my user they do show up in both Real and Cloud Authentication lists.  just data does not pass

Comment: Ohh man you are using Cloud Firestore but are reading data form RealTime Database. You have to read data like this:
`let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid)
userRef.getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in 
    guard let document = documentSnapshot?.data() else {
    }
    print(document)
}`
Use that code.

Comment: Please do not include links in questions; if the link breaks, it would invalidate the question. Please include screenshots in your question instead of a link. Also, as others have mentioned, your code is for the Real Time Data Base (RTDB) and the data in the provided link is for Firestore. You need to either re-write your code for Firestore or use the RTDB for your data.

Comment: 10-4 Jay   my bad.  Najeeb yeah I saw that.  Newb mistake.  Now im working on parsing out data from users documents.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Cloud Firestore for data storage but your code is reading data form RealTime Database. You have to read data like this:

```
let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid) 
userRef.getDocument { (documentSnapshot, error) in guard 
    let document = documentSnapshot?.data() else { 
        print(error)
        return 
    } 
    print(document) 
}
```